# RegEx to replace to given date with the current date

Tags: java, json, regex, replace

I have deserialized json to string variable where i wanted to update below variable to current date in all occurrence

`"buyDate":"2019-04-09T13:21:00.866Z",`

```
String result = content.replaceAll("(\"buyDate\":\"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\.*$)\")", "\"buyDate\":" + LocalDate.now().toString() + "\"");
```

but above logic is failing. Can someone please suggest solution.

Comment: I think `String.replaceAll` is not the best idea when it comes to manipulating JSON data... Think about deserializing the JSON to objects, manipulating their values and re-writing the JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [**parsers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743324/7571182) for parsing and amending dynamic JSON data. However, if the JSON is static and you want to achieve your result using regex; then your regex is very correct(although it can be compacted. See in answer).  You just need to use [**`LocalDateTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instance instead of [**`LocalDate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instance. Something like;

```
// Sample code. Please manipulate according to your requirements.
import java.time.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sample test String
        String content = "\"buyDate\":\"2019-04-09T13:21:00.866Z\"";
       // String result = content.replaceAll("(\"buyDate\":\"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.*)\")", "\"buyDate\":\"" 
        //+ LocalDateTime.now().toString() + "Z\"");
// COMPACTED REGEX
        String result = content.replaceAll("(\"buyDate\":\".*?\"", "\"buyDate\":\"" 
        + LocalDateTime.now().toString() + "Z\"");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
// Outputs: "buyDate":"2020-06-16T09:33:38.276Z" a.t. online IDE's local time.
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/HJRjuzU6U)

---

If you want to replace only date value leaving time and zero-hour format as it is(although I don't see any practical reason to do so); then you could try this:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate dt = LocalDate.now();
        final String regex = "\"buyDate\":\"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})T";
        final String string = "\"buyDate\":\"2019-04-09T13:21:00.866Z\"";
        DateTimeFormatter formatDateToday=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd");
        final String subst = "\"buyDate\":\""+ dt.format(formatDateToday) +"T";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

- I used [**`DateTimeFormatter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class for formatting the Date.
- I used `Pattern` and `Matcher` class to match only the dates in the given JSON string.

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/SJH2-7UpU)

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a `$` and then its followed by `\"` in the regex? 
This will suffice `"(\"buyDate\":\"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.*)\")"`.

Your final code will be like

```
String result = content.replaceAll("(\"buyDate\":\"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.*)\")", "\"buyDate\":" + LocalDate.now().toString() + "\"");
```

You should use `java.time` package classes for cleaner manipulation.